# Determine particle proximity

Tags: math, data-structures, computer-science, simulation

I am animating particles moving from the top to the bottom of my screen at a random speed. They are also randomly placed on top of the screen.

Is there a data structure I could use to determine the proximity of particles relative to each other within a certain radius without checking every particle. I've tried searching around, but unsure of what to even search for.

Comment: There is a way to put them into regions, I have forgotten the name though. Essentially, it's graphically represented by a grid with a decent step size. All of the particles in the same region are in an array (or whatever), so you really only need to check in the region and  in adjacent regions. I know that NVidia used a similar technique when simplifying n-body galaxy collision simulations.

Comment: You should research collision detection.

Comment: How complicated are the individual particle paths?

Comment: Is this for a simulation? If so how complicated are the individual particle paths? A faster route might be to look for proximity some number of steps down the road rather than at the current simulation step. Chances are it can at least help determine which particles might get close several steps down the line.

Comment: Yea you're correct. I tried determining the proximity for every step of the path but from a performance point of view its not feasible. I just have set location on the path to determine proximities.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments and through some more researching I stumbled across R-trees. It seems to meet all the criteria I was looking for. There are alternatives but hope this helps anyone else looking for a similar solution.